# Are we no longer allowed to use header markdown?

Tags: bug

In trying to post an answer today, I found none of my headers rendered. When I typed `> ### Some Header` it rendered the `###` rather than making the line into an `<h3>`.

#### Header

I also tried using `===` on the next line, which rendered correctly in the preview but not in the answer (still just displaying literally rather than creating a header element).

## Alternate Header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### This is a test

The above (`> ### This is a test`) should work. It does *not* work (anymore) if you omit the space between `###` and `This`; that's because CommonMark does not allow it and we've [recently switched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232) to that Markdown specification.

> ###This is a test

The above quote is produced by the Markdown `> ###This is a test`